# Ionic focus gets removed from input-emelent

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'd like to build a multiple input area for e-mail addresses. I started building a prototype with pure angularjs, that worked:

[angular-fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/marcelly/y0a579xv/20/)

The input field gets displayed if one of the elements get clicked:

```
$scope.focus = true;
```

This is the variable I need to show the input field. If focus is false, the input field is not displayed. Or if the area receives a click-event.

In order to set the focus on the input, in order to start typing directly, I use:

```
element[0].focus();
```

That works unless I use the ionic-framework. As soon as the input got the focus, it's taken away:

[ionic-fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/marcelly/tfxf1npa/)

Why is the focus taken away by using ionic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`autofocus` seems to be the problem. it will instantly fire a blur event and cause to hide the input field again. Try to manually to focus on the input field after the input is visible (with $timeout). See http://jsfiddle.net/awqtsLpy/. I moved the `edit` function to the directive.link section to get access to the element.

```
app.directive('emailRecipients', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        controller: function ($scope) {
            $scope.focus = false;
            $scope.addressees = [];
            var i = 10;
            while (i) {
                $scope.addressees.push({
                    "name": i
                });
                i--;
            }
        },
        link: function ($scope, element) {
            $scope.click = function () {
                $scope.focus = !$scope.focus;
                $scope.value = null;
            }
            $scope.deleteFromInput = function ($event) {

                $event.stopPropagation();
            }
            $scope.edit = function ($event, addressee) {
                $event.stopPropagation();
                $scope.value = addressee;
                addressee.editable = true;
                $scope.focus = true;
                $timeout(function () {
                    element.find('input').focus();
                });
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: the $timeout works in my version as well. I tried out scope.$apply and setTimeout before, these don't work. :)